# changing parent when hover on child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following menu structure:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="first leaf"><a href="#" title="" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li class="expanded"><a href="#" title="Products">Products</a>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="first leaf"><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
      <li class="last leaf"><a href="#">Product 4</a></li>
    </ul
  <li>
  <li class="expanded"><a href="#" title="Products">Products Level 2</a>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="first leaf"><a href="#">Product 5</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Product 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  <li>
</ul>
```

What I'm looking to do is, when the `Product 1` item is hovered, I want the parent `Products` menu item to change.

I've looked into CSS to do this, by trying to target the parent based on the child, but seems like it cannot be done.

Can this be done in jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: CSS based answer >> http://jsfiddle.net/wKqB9/3/ << - However it depends on what you going to change. - > http://stackoverflow.com/a/10804904/297641

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want it to be changed?

**Edit:** Updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wKqB9/3/) for 2 li submenu's

**Just with CSS:**

```
ul.menu li { display: inline-block; margin: 3px;  padding: 5px; vertical-align: top;}

ul.menu li:hover { font-weight: bold; background-color: green; }

ul.menu, ul.menu li:hover ul, ul.menu li:hover ul.menu li { font-weight: normal; background-color: white; }
ul.menu li:hover ul.menu li:hover { font-weight: bold; background-color: green; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wKqB9/1/) - Font & background

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wKqB9/2/) - Just the font

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eqjm0uk8/3/ I have this but I don't want the child to be changed. Only the parent changed when hovered over the child.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menu > .expanded > .menu > li > a').on('hover', function(e) {
    var li = $(this).closest('.expanded').find('a:first');
    if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
        li.css('background', '#f00');
    } else {
        li.css('background', '#fff');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/U9YVj/1/)**

or

```
$('li.leaf').on('hover', function(e) {
   var li = $(this).closest('.expanded').find('a:first');
   if(e.type == 'mouseenter') li.css('background', '#fff');
   else li.css('background', '#f00');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QuEA8/1/)**

**According to your edit**

Your HTML markup have some problems, resolve them.

I think my code is working with new makeup also.

See **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/cELJ6/)**

Comment: That's almost what I needed. I have updated my question to include a second drop down. This seems to make the jquery do strange things

Comment: I'm almost there, just a small quirk, which can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/cELJ6/1/ - When I hover hover `Products`, it's fine, then I hover over over it again and it's grey. the color needs to be white. The JS seems to override this. Any ideas?

Comment: @terrid25 where do you get grey? please clarify

Comment: Ok, when I hover over `Products` and then the items below it, it's fine. When i hover away then back again, the li nk colour of `Products` is now #777. I need it to be white. It should only be #777 in a non-active/hover state

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a:contains('Product 1')").hover(function(){
   $('[title="Products"]').addClass('changed');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ULALG/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('li.first').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('li.expanded').children('a').css('font-weight', 'bold');
}, function() {
    $(this).closest('li.expanded').children('a').css('font-weight', 'normal');
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ppeKY/)**.

The example just bolds the products menu when hovering over the product 1 list item, but you could do anything you needed to instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/KZdkV/16/

```
$('.hoverchange').hover(function() {
    $('.expanded').replaceWith('<a href="#" title="NewStuff">NewStuff</a>');
});​
```

I changed a bit of your classes though. Look at the link for the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add an id to the first ul and then like this:

```
$(".menu .menu li a").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).parents("#root > li").addClass('test');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).parents("#root > li").removeClass('test');
    }     
);
```

on **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harpax/Kwrk6/)**